# Compute CID of data in Go

Tags: ipfs, filecoin

I need to compute the CID of some data in Golang, right now I'm using this code, but the CID I receive is different than what I get when I upload the file to Filecoin or add it to a Lotus node.

This is my code:

```
"github.com/ipfs/go-cid"
ma "github.com/multiformats/go-multiaddr"
mh "github.com/multiformats/go-multihash"

func Cid(data []byte) {
    hash, err := mh.Sum(data, mh.SHA2_256, -1)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    c, err := cid.V1Builder{Codec: cid.DagProtobuf, MhType: mh.SHA2_256, MhLength: -1}.Sum(hash)

    fmt.Println("Filecoin CID:", c.String())
}
```

If I have a file with the content `Hello`, the above function prints the following cid: `bafybeievjvim3p2qexhlxek5yqftxsizm6fx2mtrgrsyfx43f52sozkwga`
If I add it to Lotus, or upload to Filecoin I get: `bafkreiayl6g3gitr7ys7kyng7sjywlrgimdoymco3jiyab6rozecmoazne`

I would like to have a function that returns me the same CID.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to chunk the data as well. My updated code is below. If I now upload the same file to Filecoin I get the same CID.

```
 import (
     "bytes"
     "fmt"
     "io"
     "os"
     "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
     chunker "github.com/ipfs/boxo/chunker"
     "github.com/ipfs/go-cid"
     "github.com/libp2p/go-libp2p/core/host"
     mh "github.com/multiformats/go-multihash"
)

func Cid(data []byte) {
// Create an IPLD UnixFS chunker with size 1 MiB
chunks := chunker.NewSizeSplitter(bytes.NewReader(data), 1024*1024)

// Concatenate the chunks to build the DAG
var buf bytes.Buffer
for {
    chunk, err := chunks.NextBytes()
    if err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    buf.Write(chunk)
}

// Calculate the CID for the DAG
hash, err := mh.Sum(buf.Bytes(), mh.SHA2_256, -1)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

// Create a CID version 1 (with multibase encoding base58btc)
c := cid.NewCidV1(cid.DagProtobuf, hash)

// Print the CID as a string
fmt.Println("IPFS CID in Golang:", c.String())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To correctly calculate the CID, the DAG should be built over the chunked data, as in IPFS CID represents DAG, but not the data itself. [lajosdeme](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10706839/lajosdeme)'s answer works for the files that are not so large because they could be represented by the linear list with a single branch containing the whole DAG. Otherwise, this method does not work. The proper way here is to call the DAG builder on the `/dev/null` blockstore. The easiest way to do this is to use routines from [Boxo](https://github.com/ipfs/boxo) library.

Then the exact code for **files** (it does not support directories, this require additional efforts) looks like:

```golang
import (
    "bytes"
    "os"
    chunker "github.com/ipfs/boxo/chunker"
    "github.com/ipfs/go-cid"
    dsync "github.com/ipfs/go-datastore/sync"
    multicodec "github.com/multiformats/go-multicodec"
    "github.com/ipfs/boxo/ipld/unixfs/importer/balanced"
    uih "github.com/ipfs/boxo/ipld/unixfs/importer/helpers"
    "github.com/ipfs/go-datastore"
    blockstore "github.com/ipfs/boxo/blockstore"
    "github.com/ipfs/boxo/blockservice"
    offline "github.com/ipfs/boxo/exchange/offline"
    "github.com/ipfs/boxo/ipld/merkledag"
)

func Cid(filename string) string {
    fileData, err := os.ReadFile(filename)
    if err != nil {panic(err)}
    fileReader := bytes.NewReader(fileData)
    ds := dsync.MutexWrap(datastore.NewNullDatastore())
    bs := blockstore.NewBlockstore(ds)
    bs = blockstore.NewIdStore(bs)
    bsrv := blockservice.New(bs, offline.Exchange(bs))
    dsrv := merkledag.NewDAGService(bsrv)
    ufsImportParams := uih.DagBuilderParams{
        Maxlinks:  uih.DefaultLinksPerBlock, // Default max of 174 links per block
        RawLeaves: true,
        CidBuilder: cid.V1Builder{ // Use CIDv1 for all links
            Codec:    uint64(multicodec.Raw),
            MhType:   uint64(multicodec.Sha2_256), //SHA2-256
            MhLength: -1,
        },
        Dagserv: dsrv,
        NoCopy:  false,
    }
    ufsBuilder, err := ufsImportParams.New(chunker.NewSizeSplitter(fileReader, chunker.DefaultBlockSize)) // 256KiB chunks
    if err != nil {
        return cid.Undef.String()
    }
    nd, err := balanced.Layout(ufsBuilder)
    if err != nil {
        return cid.Undef.String()
    }
    return nd.Cid().String()
}
```

The viable example lives here: https://github.com/twdragon/ipfs-cid-local